# How can I compare the excel and csv column using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, compare

I just want to compare column A from wedartmore.csv to column C of Book1.xlsx and want to get index where values are same.

```
import csv 

# opening the CSV file 
with open('wedartmore.csv', mode ='r')as file: 

# reading the CSV file 
csvFile = csv.reader(file) 

# displaying the contents of the CSV file 
for lines in csvFile: 
        print(lines[0]) 

# Reading excel file:

import xlrd 

loc = ("Book1") 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
```

I am using these two methods for reading files but don't know how to apply condition for comparing.
Here are the files: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uhNg6XIE0h18lG3qqcO9ZnTzwe-JQZl7)

Comment: _I am using these two methods for reading files but don’t know how to apply condition for comparing._ That’s quite vague, can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 import pandas as pd

 df_csv = pd.read_csv('wedartmore.csv')
 df_xlsx = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
 merged_data = df_csv.merge(df_xlsx, left_on = 'Name', right_on = 'Artist')

 print(merged_data)
```

There are two common rows in the CSV and xlsx files.

Please let me know if it worked for you.